# Codeigniter, Add subfolders and files in a treeview

Tags: php, jquery, codeigniter, treeview

I am trying to implement a treeview where users can add subfolders and files.

I'm using codeigniter and jquery for this , I can see the treeview structure but i don't know how i can implement the directory and file creation(managing) functionality.

For example, in country 1, citrus subfolder i'd like to add another folder and then files to this new folder.

![ treeview ][1]

[VIEW] :

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Files</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<style type="text/css">

 ul { list-style: none;
      padding-left: 20px;
      cursor: pointer;
  }
  li {
      padding-left: 20px;
      margin:2px;
  }

  .folder { background:#eee  url('../img/16x16/folder.png') no-repeat;
             }
  .file { background:#eee url('../img/16x16/file.png') no-repeat;}   

</style> 
</head>

<body>
<div id="files">
<?php //print_r($folders);?>
</div>

<div id="files-operation">

</div>  

<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function() {
var files = <?php echo json_encode($folders); ?>;
var file_tree = build_file_tree(files);
file_tree.appendTo('#files');


function build_file_tree(files) {

    var tree = $('<ul>');

    for (x in files) {

        if (typeof files[x] == "object") {
            var span = $('<span>').html(x).appendTo(
                $('<li>').appendTo(tree).addClass('folder')
            );
            var subtree = build_file_tree(files[x]).hide();
            span.after(subtree);
            span.click(function() {
                $(this).parent().find('ul:first').toggle();
            });

        } else {
            $('<li>').html(files[x]).appendTo(tree).addClass('file').click(function(){
                window.location=$(this).find("a").attr("href");return false;})


        }

    }

    return tree;

}
});  

</script>
```

[CONTROLLER] :

```
function display()
{
    $data['folders'] = directory_map('./vinefresh/');
    $data['contenido'] = "index";
    $this->load->view('plantilla',$data);
}
```

My goal is to be able to make subdirectories and adding files dynamicaly, but how do i get the path if i want to create a subfolder within Citrus or any other subfolder?

thanks in advance